# Dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a program which takes a CSV file and saves the CSV data into a Dictionary and then compares the **keys** of that dictionary with **values fetched from the database**.
And If a dictionary key is equal to a database value then I want to save that **said key** with it's **respected value** in an empty dictionary for later use.

But I am unable to understand how to save the values.

```py
def LCR(request):
    template = "LCR\LCR.html"
    dest = [92,923,9234,925]
    rates = {} # my main dictionary which gets populated later on
    ratelist = {}


    csv_file = open(r'.\adoc.csv')

    #Example data of the csv file 
    #Dest , Rate
    #980, 0.205
    #981, 0.305
    #982, 0.015


    data_set = csv_file.read().decode("UTF-8")
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=str(u",")):
        rates[column[0]] = column[1]

    for desNum in dest: #Int gets converted to str
        desNum = str(desNum)
        # print type(desNum)

        for num in desNum:

                for venNum in rates:

                    for VN in venNum:
                        # print rates

                        if num[:2] == VN[:2]:
                            ratelist[venNum] = [rates.values()]
```

I expect to populate ratelist dictionary with both the key and it's respected value.

Comment: Well, you're not closing your file - you should open it with "with" and set nest your code within that to start with. Then can't you just check if column[0] is in dest and populate ratelist directly if it is? There seems to be a lot of unnecessary code in there, if I've understood what you want to do correctly.

Comment: Yes I know that the file needs closing but that has nothing to do with the asked question. The question is how to save the value of the key.

Comment: That would be addressed in sentence 2 ;)

Comment: if i wanted to do such a thing why would have I posted the question in the first place.

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mcve] ? We do not know what is in the `dest` variable for instance.

Comment: let me update my question @IMCoins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in rates.items():

                for VN in key:
                    if ...:

                        ratelist[key] = value
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks